# convert column to table header in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
identifier_1         measure         Value     identifier_2
 abc                 height         12         oii
 abc                 weight         122         oii
 abc                 eye_color       green      Oii
cde                  height         43          lkj
cde                  weight         123         lkj
cde                  eye_color         blue     lkj
fgh                   height         32         mnb
fgh                  weight         125         mnb
fgh                eye_color         black      mnb
```

I want to transform the column "measure" into a table header, and the corresponding cell in column value, to be its value, like:

```
identifier_1    height  weight  eye_color   identifier_2
abc             12      122      green       oii
cde             43      123     blue         lkj
fgh             32      125      black      mnb
```

I tried the pivot function in pandas but couldn't reach the required result.

Comment: use the bracket "code" feature to show us what you are talking about, please

Comment: Just a small reality check: is it guaranteed that the same measure won't appear twice for the same combination of identifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['identifier_1','identifier_2','measure'])['Value']
         .unstack()
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df1)
  identifier_1 identifier_2 eye_color height weight
0          abc          oii     green     12    122
1          cde          lkj      blue     43    123
2          fgh          mnb     black     32    125
```